# android SMS Inbox

Tags: android

How can we insert date in content://sms/inbox.
i m using this code

```
ContentValues sms = new ContentValues();
sms.put("date", long date);
objContext.getContentResolver().insert( Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),sms);
```

plz give me any solution.

Thanx
khan

Comment: This content provider is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: did you make this work? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sms.put("date", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```